# LLDB Pass-thru Environment Vars

Tags: lldb

How can I get LLDB to pass its environment to the executable it runs?

As in, if I run `FOO=BAR lldb a.out`, I want `a.out`'s environment to have `FOO=BAR`. 
I know I can do this using `process launch -v FOO=BAR`, but I have quite a few env vars and don't want to type it every time.

Comment: I cannot test this at the moment, but I think that `FOO=BAR lldb a.out` *does* pass `FOO=BAR` to the launched process.

Answer (score 0):

lldb should do this by default.  There is a setting to control this behavior:

```
settings set target.inherit-env {true/false}
```

but the default is "true" so this should already be happening (it does for me...)

Note it doesn't make as much sense to pass the environment to a remote process, so Xcode may defeat this setting for iOS debugging.